# Calculation particular row mod 10^9+7 of pascal table

Tags: algorithm, math

what i  want to store is a particular row of pascal table elements mod 10^9+7  in an array i tried to code it but it is failing somewhere when value is huge of like 10^5
 here is the code. i have tried to apply modular inverse here and modular arithmetic here mod is 10^9+7

```
void pascal_row(ll n){
memset(soo,0,MAX);
soo[0] = 1; //First element is always 1
for(ll i=1; i<n/2+1; i++){ //Progress up, until reaching the middle value
   soo[i] = (  ( soo[i-1] %mod ) * (((   (n-i+1)%mod * calcInverse(i,mod)%mod) % mod ))%mod)%mod;


}
for(ll i=n/2+1; i<=n; i++){ //Copy the inverse of the first part
    soo[i] = soo[n-i]%mod;
}
}
```

here is what my modular inverse function look

```
long long calcInverse(long long a, long long n)
{
long long t = 0, newt = 1;
long long r = n, newr = a;
while (newr != 0) {
    auto quotient = r /newr;
    tie(t, newt) = make_tuple(newt, t- quotient * newt);
    tie(r, newr) = make_tuple(newr, r - quotient * newr);
}
if (r > 1)
    throw runtime_error("a is not invertible");
if (t < 0)
    t += n;
return t;
}
```

Please tell what is the correct way of doing this Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a modular inverse?

Comment: because the formula which i found was soo[i] = soo[i-1]*(n-i+1)/i
so inorder to take the modulus i had too use modular inverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a relationship between the elements of Pascal's triangle and the choose function (where n choose r = n!/(r!*(n-r)!).)  Specifically, starting from zero, the n'th row and r'th column of Pascal's triangle is n choose r.  To find a particular row, you know what n you want, and then you should iterate over the possible values of r, find n choose r, and then take your modulus.

I'd recommend Java's BigInteger class for this, because it will handle any overflow errors you might be getting.